# Android Cocos2d-x Marker Felt.ttf is not a valid font file

Tags: android, build, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x, file-permissions

I've recently started learning cocos2d-x for android. When I was building a new project for android, the build stops because of error

```
Unable to add 'D:\cocos2d-x-2.1.5\cocos2d-x-2.1.5\projects\Clicktchen\proj.android\assets\fonts\Marker Felt.ttf': Zip add failed
```

When I opened the font file, it says

[image]

if I copy it outside the project folder, it can be opened.

I've unchecked the 'readonly' permission and downloaded a new font, but it still the same
any help is appreciated.. THX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved a similar problem by giving all the permissions to the project folder (and subfolders/files) via cygwin (chmod -R 777 YOURDIR)